# How can I reset my many chosen-select boxes values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-chosen

I have a problem with using a chosen-select plugin.
I have many select boxes and I made it using javascript code.
I want to reset all my select box when I change my "default-chosen" class, but in my screen the showing text is a default message ("select an option ...") not a my message "not chosen".

This is not real code, but similar.

```js
function appendSelectBox(i) {
 $(myTable).append(
   "<select id=\select-a" + i + "\" class=\"form-control chosen-select for-history select-a\">" +
     "<option value=\"-1\">not chosen</option>" +
   "</select>");
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   appendSelectBox(i);
}


$(".select-term").chosen().change(function(event) {
  var trIndex = tableForm.getTrIndex($(this));
                tableForm.addTermUrl(trIndex);
 });
$(".default-chosen").chosen().change(function(event) {
 // here is the code that remove selected option and set default value
})
```

I tried all codes like bottom codes.

```js
$('.select-a').find('option:first-child').prop('selected', true).end().trigger('chosen:updated');


$('.select-a').find('option').removeAttr('selected').end().trigger('chosen:updated');


$('.select-a').val(-1).trigger("chosen:update");
$('.select-a').val(-1).trigger("liszt:update");
$('.select-a').val("-1").trigger("chosen:update");
$('.select-a').val("").trigger("chosen:update");
```

please help,, :[

Comment: Can you provide your current working codes ? Its not easy to fully understand your question without providing some workable codes.

Comment: The only "jquery-chosen" plugin i looked at on my google search statet on the first page that you can change the default message of your select by using `data-placeholder="YOUR DEFAULT TEXT..." `

Comment: @dev_junwen sorry, it is very complex and the code is my company code, so I can't update it. But, I found the solution. Thank your answer

Comment: @Lapskaus Yes but I didn't want the placeholder. it is the just kind of some values what set default message. thanks your comment

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my chosen change event listener was reset, so I have to re-register in my code..